# Meaning of "country-specific"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> Before the United States joined, half **the country-specific votes** condemned Israel. During the first six years the United States was a member, resolutions critical of Israel dropped to one-fifth. U.S. membership also led to a sharp decrease in the number of special sessions that focused exclusively on Israel’s treatment of the Palestinians.  [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/us-expected-to-back-away-from-un-human-rights-council/2018/06/19/a49c2d0c-733c-11e8-b4b7-308400242c2e_story.html?utm_term=.07cfe256e904)

What does "country-specific votes" mean?
When I searchd for country-specific,
Cambridge says

> used to describe a product or service that is designed for a particular country, rather than for many countries [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/country-specific)

Then does "country-specific votes" mean the votes targetting Israel,
or the votes specific countries attend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at [the resolutions from a UNHRC session](https://www.unwatch.org/resolutions-voting-results-35th-hrc-session/) is enlightening. The resolutions are categorized, one of the categories being "Condemnatory Country-Specific Resolutions". The "Condemnatory Country-Specific Resolutions" are each about human rights situations in specific countries (in the linked list, we have Syria, Belarus and Eritrea).

So, "country-specific votes" in this case would mean votes about a resolution targetting Israel.